# terminal with custom command

Tags: linux, terminal, shell, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint 13 (Mate). I have edited my mate-terminal profile using custom command as follows

```
mate-terminal --full-screen
```

By mistake i haven't set the default profile to load. So terminal is starting.
"--full screen" flag is used because I wanted to start terminal in full-screen mode every time.

May be it has other problem also. Can anyone please suggest some solution.

Comment: `So terminal is starting` Could you clarify what the issue is?  Is it not starting full-screen like you want it to?

Comment: Yeah, Terminal is starting, but not getting any $ promt.. so only black screen in full-screen mode... The flag is working properly..

Comment: Okay.  You should edit that information into your question, then.